# What's the best way to turn MySQL results into simple array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been struggling with this problem for days, with the help of many programmers, with no results. I have a table that looks like this:

```
meta_id  |  post_id  |  meta_key  |  meta_value
---------|-----------|------------|-------------------
46922    |  5923     |  adlink    | htp://whatever.com
46923    |  5923     |  subloc    | Menu Page
46924    |  5923     |  size      | Premium
46924    |  5923     |  location  | Washington
46924    |  5923     |  image1    | 5924
46924    |  5923     |  image2    | 5925    
46925    |  5928     |  adlink    | htp://whatever.com
46926    |  5928     |  subloc    | Regular Page
46927    |  5928     |  size      | Standard
46927    |  5928     |  location  | Idaho
46927    |  5928     |  image1    | 5926
46927    |  5928     |  image2    | 5927
```

I have the following query that returns the specific results I'm looking for, but formatted just like the table; i.e., with many resultant rows with some common post_id - what I NEED is to create an array or resultant table from which I can access the information as if each DISTINCT post_id creates a row with the data unique to that ID, like this:

```
id   |  adlink            |  sublock    |  size   | location   | image1   | image2
-----|--------------------|-------------|---------|------------|----------|---------
5923 | htp://whatever.com | Menu Page   | Premium | Washington | 5924     | 5925 
5928 | htp://whatever.com | regular Page| Premium | Idaho      | 5926     | 5927
```

here's the query that returns the right information:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM wp_postmeta 
 WHERE post_id IN (
                    SELECT post_id 
                      FROM wp_postmeta 
                     WHERE (
                                meta_value LIKE '%Washington%'
                            AND meta_key = 'location'
                            )
```

Comment: You need some SQL-fu. PHP unnecssary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation to pivot your data

```sql
SELECT post_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'adlink'   THEN meta_value END) adlink,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'sublock'  THEN meta_value END) sublock,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'size'     THEN meta_value END) size,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'location' THEN meta_value END) location,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'image1'   THEN meta_value END) image1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'image2'   THEN meta_value END) image2
  FROM wp_postmeta
 GROUP BY post_id
```

Output:

```
| POST_ID |             ADLINK |      SUBLOCK |     SIZE |   LOCATION | IMAGE1 | IMAGE2 |
|---------|--------------------|--------------|----------|------------|--------|--------|
|    5923 | htp://whatever.com |    Menu Page |  Premium | Washington |   5924 |   5925 |
|    5928 | htp://whatever.com | Regular Page | Standard |      Idaho |   5926 |   5927 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43b74/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

You can build result table in PHP code. Similar to this:

```
$result[$row["post_id"]][$row["meta_key"]] = $row["meta_value"];
```

Where $row - is one row from myssql result

Comment: I'm hoping to find a simpler solution than building one table of unique post_id, then iterating through the other looking for distinct ids to do it...